# Stand alone Salesforce Lightning app?

Tags: lightning-apps

Does anyone know if it's possible to use Salesforce Lightning to create a standalone mobile app? or do you have to always use the Salesforce1 app?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Brad, technically when you create a [Lightning application bundle](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/apps_overview.htm), you *are* creating a standalone mobile app, assuming that you've applied responsive design principles when building your app. If you're talking about creating an app that can be downloaded through the App Store or Google Play, perhaps you can incorporate your Lightning app into Salesforce's documentation for [developing hybrid apps for iOS and for Android](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_a_Mobile_SDK_Hybrid_App_for_Android).

Answer (score 1):

Currently Lightning Applocation can only be used in Salesforce1 mobile. You can find some useful informations about Lightning FAQ in below links:

https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_FAQ

http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/salesforce-faq-part-20-lightning-questions/